# Is there a way to call some code after subclass initialization in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to execute some code after the subclass already did all it's initialization, for example:

```
abstract class A(a:String) {
  var sum = 0
  def add(n:Int) = { sum += n; sum }
  def verify = if (sum > 10) () else throw new Exception
  ... initialize subclass ...
  verify
}
class B extends A("In A") { 
  val smth = add(50)
  // I want to avoid calling `verify` here
}
val b = new B
println(b.smth) // 50
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  The code you posted works.  Did you expect it not to?  What's the "some method" you want to call?  What's the expected output of doing so?

Comment: @dhg - The code I posted prints "In B" and "In A" in wrong order. I need to call println("In A"), after all initialization code in B already was executed.

Comment: Is there a reason you need "Something!" to be printed first?  In your example, initializing `smith` last makes no difference because the classes end up the same.

Comment: @dhg - I can point you to the codebase, and github project, and it's wiki with detailed explanation. But for the sake of the example, I kept it simple. In real code, `A` state gets mutated, and some verification is required to execute after all calls from `B` happened. Right now, I just require the user to call `verify` after his code, but it is redundant and not safe.

Comment: Keeping the code simple for the question is good, but just as long as you aren't simplifying away the real issue.  Your last comment makes me think that a factory method that calls `verify` for the user would be a good route.  But maybe you could update your question to actually include the `verify` situation so we can be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I found the answer. I decided to go with the DelayedInit trait approach - I just execute the delayed code (and count number of times it was executed), then execute the needed code when I think that I've seen enough initializations (one for each class in the extension hierarchy). I wrapped it into a trait:

```
trait AfterInit extends DelayedInit {
  def afterInit
  private var initCount = 0
  private def getInitNumber(clazz: Class[_]):Int =
    if (clazz.getSuperclass == classOf[java.lang.Object]) 0 else getInitNumber(clazz.getSuperclass) + 1
  final def delayedInit(x: => Unit) {
    x
    initCount += 1
    if (getInitNumber(this.getClass) + 1 == initCount) afterInit
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
abstract class A(id:String) extends AfterInit {
  var sum = 0
  def add(n:Int) = { sum += n; sum }
  def afterInit = if (sum > 10) () else throw new Exception
}

class B extends A("B") {
  val add1 = add(50)
}
new B // no exception

class C extends A("C") {
  val add2 = add(5)
}
new C // exception is thrown, since the `sum` was too small
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use lazy vals in B, or use the "early initializer" so that the vals in B are initialized before the vals in A.  Here'a an excellent description of how these two options work: https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order

Comment: No I cant use lazy vals in B! Because code in A, that mutates that A, *must* be executed before `verify` is called!

Comment: Then you will need to use the early initialization syntax.  Kind of clunky, but that's the only way to have subclass logic executed before the superclass initializer.

Comment: and what about DelayedInit? It allows us to do something like this, but I failed to achieve the needed effect.

Comment: Seems I found the way to execute superclass logic after subclass initialization - see my answer.